# Accidentally added my entire desktop to the explorer tab in VS Code. How can I close it without losing anything?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have no idea how I did this, but I accidentally added my entire desktop to VS Code in the Explorer View. I have a mac. My desktop is now a tab to click on to drop down and click through files. I don't know how to remove those without losing everything.

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue!  I would recommend either self-answering to share your solution with others, or, if you feel the question/answer doesn't really have value for others in the future, then delete the post entirely.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: This not exactly a programming problem. You might consider deleting your question.

Comment: @endo64 software tools commonly used by programmers is on topic

Answer (score 2):

You probably selected your user home directory as the folder to open as a workspace folder when invoking `File: Open Folder...` or a related action / command. Just close the workspace using either the `File > Close Folder` menu item, or <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>. You won't lose anything by closing the folder.