# vsc/git "too many changes were detected. Only the first 10000 will be shown below"

Tags: git, github, repository, vscode-debugger

Beginner coder here who attempted to connect my vsc and github in an effort to update my code, but I think i did something wrong because now in the source control folder i have over 10,000 files that need changes?

I tried to connect github to vsc, and connect repositories i think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76941933/11107541 ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.